# ASP.NET 4.5 hiding virtual directory in URL

Tags: asp.net, url, virtual, asp.net-4.5

I am using GoDaddy which forced my web site into a virtual directory - lots of problems with styles and URLs. Now I would like to get rid of the virtual directory from the URL: `http://www.mywebsite.com/**theWebsite**/Place/Contact`

The theWebsite virtual directory is rather redundant. I have the URLs mapped so removing the virtual works just fine everywhere. Occasionally the virtual directory disappears and then returns.  I can make no sense of when it disappears and reappears.

Once I brought it up and it only showed the base URL www.thesignupplace.com and would not show the HTML on a View Page Source. The underlying URLs all worked even they did not show.  I have no idea how I caused that to happen and I would like to know how to make it happen again.

There was an post in 2011 like this but it does not make any sense in Visual Studio 2013 with ASP.NET 4.5 with the RouteConfig.cs class.

I tried a base/href suggestion that then changed my localhost to the website and did not get rid of the virtual directory in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If your entire website is contained in the virtual directory then I think you could just set it as the document root in GoDaddy's Hosting Settings.